# Compiling FFmpeg 3.1.1 for x86 using Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, ffmpeg, android-ndk

The newest version of `FFmpeg` is `3.1.1`. After version `3.1`, I can't compile `FFmpeg` for `x86`.(But `3.0.2` or earlier versions can be compiled.)

The terminal shows `ld: error: libavutil/../compat/strtod.o: incompatible target`.

My OS is `Xubuntu 14.04 x86` and `x86_64`.(I have tried both of them.)

My `NDK` version is `r10e(x86)` and `r12b(x86_64)`.

When I compile `FFmpeg 3.0.2`, it has no error.

This is my configure:

```
./configure \
--prefix="${PREFIX}" \
--enable-shared \
--disable-static \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--cross-prefix="${PREFIX}/bin/i686-linux-android-" \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=x86 \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot="${PREFIX}/sysroot" \
--extra-cflags="" \
--extra-ldflags="" \
--extra-libs="" \
--disable-debug
```

`${PREFIX}` is a directory path used for `--install-dir` option while running `make-standalone-toolchain.sh` which is a tool in Android NDK.

It only happens while I compile `FFmpeg` for `x86`. `ARM` architecture is ok.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and found a workaround.  Make sure to remove "compat/strtod.o" and "compat/strtod.d" if you previously built for another architecture.  For some reason these do not get rebuilt if you change architecture in 3.1.1, but it worked fine in previous versions.  You should also do a "make clean" before building.

Comment: @Dave You saved my life, probably 6 hours of it.

Comment: I did that in my script "rm compat/strtod.o rm compat/strtod.d" and now i dont't have to worry about the problem, was annoying and to be honest wasn't easy to figure out, thanks